# What's wrong with my syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm getting "undefined is not a function" at line 40, I'm guessing it's syntax but need some help.

I recently converted the array to an object and I don't think i'm calling it properly

any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

http://pastebin.com/423S1tRe

Comment: Please put your code in your question.

Comment: That is fairly obvious: you are using an undefined object as a function.

Comment: Put `console.log(current26)` after line 35 and See What Happens (tm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current26` variable contains a string, and a string doesn't have any `setZIndex` method, so that's the function that is undefined.

I think that you might want to run the code instead of putting it in strings:

```
rcp26[1950] = L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.oegndfvv');
rcp26[1960] = L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.3c693r3a');
rcp26[1970] = L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.jsetqfnl');
...
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem! (just removed the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a syntax error. Look carefully at line 40

```
                    var overlay = current26.setZIndex(1).addTo(map);
```

What is `current26`? It's a string. It does not have a property `setZIndex`. Therefore, `current26.setZIndex` is undefined, and when you try to call `current26.setZIndex(1)`, you get the error. Perhaps you want something more like

```
                    var overlay = $(current26).zIndex(1).addTo(map);
```